# Dynamically fill an excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to create an excel file dynamically. Here is my code, but I don't know how to write a specific string into each cell. I just want to have the same string in all cells.

The example (the one I'm trying to follow) writes the same text in each cell, but I want to change

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Range aRange = ws.get_Range("A1", "A"+words.Length);
//Obtain the range
if (aRange == null){ 
    Console.WriteLine("Could not get a range. Check to be sure you have the correct versions of the office DLLs.");
}

Object[] args = new Object[1];
//   args[0] = 6; <- this is the default

for (var i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
   args[0] = words[i];
}
aRange.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, aRange, args);
```

I hve added that `for` loop, but I don't know how to write it to put in each cell, each word.

edit: in all rows, the system writes words[last]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of objects needs to have the same size as the number of words.

```
Object[] args = new Object[words.Length];
```

Then you can assign words properly to items of that array inside the `for` loop.

```
args[i] = words[i];
```

In your code you are overwriting the value of the *only* item in the array (`args[0]`) in each iteration of the loop, ending up with the last word as the value.